# Change ADD TO CART button text on the product price on the Store page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce can we change the "ADD TO CART" button text near the product price on the Store page?

I have attached image:
[image: See image]

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This has been answered toons of time and you can have this on WooCommerce official docs here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with filter easily. Please try this.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text', 10 );
function my_custom_cart_button_text() {

global $product;
    if (@$product->product_type == 'simple') {
        return __(get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().@$product->price, 'woocommerce');
    } else {
        // If needed the default behavior for all other products:
        // return __('My default text', 'woocommerce');
    }
}
```

Comment: put code in functions.php file ?

Comment: @SavanDholu i have edited my function. and yes put it in functions.php

Comment: I have tested it and working. as you mentioned you want to change text only on store page(/shop) correct?

Comment: Yes working but i have display simple and variable product price  @Davinder Kumar

Comment: If it is working, accept as answer.
You will need to create a function and call with ajax for variable product for change of variation.

Comment: Code will be like this
if (@$product->product_type == 'simple' || @$product->product_type == 'variable') {

Comment: For variable product, you will need to fetch price with selected variant.

Comment: Yes working 
Thanks..

Comment: Ok, do upwote and select appepted answer for future use.

Comment: you can accept a answer by click this. http://i.prntscr.com/e3c8637bed444240a14b3b213b827d32.png